# Query for replacing a number in string

Tags: ms-access

In one Short Text column of a table such data was stored "any_text_N" where N is some number specific for each row.
I need to replace N by N+1.
Could any one provide query to do it?

Comment: Is '_N' always the rightmost character(s), and when you say 'specific' for each row, do you mean unique or is it really tied to a row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming (1) the number is always the rightmost characters, and (2) there is an underscore preceding the number, you can create a Function to parse the number and return the incremented value (see below).

Then to test it, create a query like follows (MAKE SURE YOU TEST FIRST!!!):

```
SELECT Table2.MyText, resetnbr([MyText]) AS NewVal
FROM Table2
WHERE (((Table2.MyText) Is Not Null));
```

Then to update your data:

```
UPDATE Table2 SET Table2.MyText= resetnbr([MyText])
WHERE (((Table2.MyText) Is Not Null));


Public Function ResetNbr(strIn As String) As String
'Assumes: (1) Number in rightmost position of string; (2) underscore preceeds number
Dim iLen    As Integer
Dim i       As Integer
Dim sNbr    As String

    If strIn = "" Then
        ResetNbr = strIn
        Exit Function
    End If
    iLen = Len(strIn)
    For i = iLen To 1 Step -1
        If Mid(strIn, i, 1) = "_" Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    If i > 1 Then
        sNbr = Mid(strIn, i + 1, 99)
        sNbr = sNbr + 1
        ResetNbr = left(strIn, i) & sNbr
    Else
        ' No underscore found!
        ResetNbr = strIn
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay! It was wery helpfull!